# PHP : single quote str_replace not working in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I get an strange problem.My variable **$match**,which contain the string with single quotes in it `'http://site.com'` . i want to remove the single quotes and make it to `http://site.com`.I tried below code but its not removing the single quotes.

```
   $FileName = str_replace("'", "", $match);
    echo $FileName;
```

Note : I am using Mamp.The same works fine in my cpanel.

and actually `'http://site.com'` is got from preg_match...should i convert that to string or something ? I tried (string) , still did not work.

Comment: Your code works: http://codepad.org/sMGDL31g
Sure you are using the right ' and not ' instead of `?

Comment: -1 You can be sure that `str_replace` does not have any bugs. Debug your code, please. ;)

Comment: I said it works in cpanel..but not in MAMP..read questions first before doing -1

Comment: @VishnuVishwa There's no known issue of `str_replace` on MAMP. So the code you've posted here does not have anything to do with your problem. Take a look at the code that is more platform specific.

Comment: This is completely nonsensical. I mean why don't you debug it yourself ? Try var_dump, convert the characters to HEX and compare the values, you don't need SO's help.

Comment: don't get emotional with votes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is prefect. Its giving correct output :-

```
$match="'http://site.com'";
$FileName = str_replace("'", "", $match);
echo $FileName;
```

Output:-

```
http://site.com
```

Without str_replace:-

```
'http://site.com'
```

EDIT:

TRY THIS:-

```
$FileName = str_replace('\'', '', $match);
```

Comment: nope not working in MAMP

Comment: no bro , did not work..actually 'http://site.com' is got from preg_match...should i convert that to string or something ?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the string to hex like this

```
$str= htmlentities($original_str, ENT_QUOTES); // it will convert both the single quotes and double quotes
now you can replace the hex with something like
str_replace($str,"",$original_str);
```

try if it works.

Comment: i mean most people will suggest it.. i believe

Comment: @VishnuVishwa what is what?